# What is the original input for the halting question

Tags: halting-problem

I was reading about the halting problem recently, but I couldn't quite figure something out. We take $H(x,y)$ to be a program which works out if program $x$ with input $y$ halts, and $H_2(x,y)$ to be a program which works out $H(x,y)$ and then does the opposite (if $x$ halts, $H_2$ loops, else $H_2$ ends). The halting problem as I understand it goes $H_2(x,x)$, $H_2$ will do the opposite of $x(x)$, thus $H_2(H_2)$ will do the opposite of itself and hence a contradiction. My issue here is that the inner $H_2$ requires an input as well, so what is that? If it has no input then the whole proof seems to be flawed, as it is equivalent to saying "What is $x^2$ if $x$ is orange". If the inner $H_2$'s input is another set of the same ($H_2(H_2(H_2))$)  then what is the new innermost one's input? And so on and so forth.

Furthermore, does the proof not assume that both $H_2$ (outside brackets) and $H_2$ (inside brackets) are the same, as $H_2(H_2)$ does the opposite of what is inside of its brackets, meaning that $H_2$ (code form) and $H_2$ (function form) are two fundamentally different things and so properties of one are not the same as properties of another?

Answer (score 0):

The halting problem was a mathematical problem proposed by Hilbert & Ackermann. What you are studying is the classic proof of the halting problem's undecidabilty as given by Turing. To better understand the proof's formal structure, you might read [this summary](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/nelson/courses/csc_173/computability/undecidable.html), beginning at "Is the Halting Problem Decidable?"

That will answer your question. And the gist of it is, the machine that induces the contradiction only needs one argument because the argument is a program which takes itself as its own input.

Answer (score 0):

You actually define $H_2$ to get only one input $x$, and simulate what you said when running with $H(x,x)$. Basically, $H_2(x)$ loops if $H(x,x)="true"$ and otherwise halts. Then, the proof continues by asking what value $H_2(\langle H_2\rangle)$ gets, where $\langle H_2 \rangle$ is the *text* representing the turing machine $H_2$.

Comment: This is confusing for a few reasons i) if H2(x) loops if H(x,x) = true, then H2(x) = H2(x,x), and then H2(H2) = H2(H2(H2), and if that is true then H2(H2) = H2(H2(H2(H2.... , and even that still has no input, just a string of itself. ii) If we, for example, performed H2(p), and p was equal to x^2, then what would be the output (we could work this out in our heads for h(p), obviously H(p) halts), does x^2^2 halt? it seems that it would just result in an error, and so we would be making a potentially invalid assumption that h2(h2) is even a logical question to ask. Have I misinterpreted?

Comment: If $H(x,x)=true$, then $H_2(x)$ gets stuck in an infinite loop. Notice, that I intentionally used the notation $\langle H_2\rangle$ to represent the text of the machine $H_2$, since the machine and its representation as text are two different things. You can think of it like you are writing some code in some programming language that opens the file you wrote the code in and inspects it, doing some calculation.

Comment: But so how is the question of whether H2 will halt or not halt even a valid one which can be asked? (from H2(⟨H2⟩) = H(⟨H2⟩) ). If it is just the program of H2, it cannot be asked whether or not it will halt because the program requires an input, the same way that asking will the program
`If input() == 1  
     loop
else 
 dont loop 
`
makes no sense to say does that program loop

Comment: Notice the definition of $H$ and $H_2$ carefully. $H_2$ gets **one** input $x$, and computes $H(x,x)$. Basically, it treats $x$ as a computer program and asks whether or not it halts when it is fed with the input which is the text of $x$ itself. Apart from that $H_2$ does the opposite from that value it computed. The point here, is that $H_2(\langle H_2 \rangle)$ is basically the following: compute $H(\langle H_2\rangle , \langle H_2 \rangle )$, which means, ask if $H_2$ will halt given as input its own code.

Comment: But your still essentially asking whether or not H2 on its own will halt, through a more convoluted method of H2(H2) = H(H2,H2) --> H2(<H2>) --> H(<H2>), but surely the code itself cannot give an output of whether it halts or not, because it is just code which requires an input to function. H(<h2>) can surely be analogous to my h(my example code in the previous comment) no?

Comment: @Mercury Every program/input combination either halts or does not halt. I hope that is obvious. Either it halts, or it doesn't. There is no such thing as "doesn't halt and doesn't not halt". And there is no invalid question here. Note that there is no H2(H2(H2(H2... going on. H2(<H2>) - or if you prefer H(<H2>,<H2>) is a straightforward question once you have an algorithm that can reliably calculate H.

Comment: @Mercury If you have a program H that calculates whether any program/input will halt, that means it can calculate whether H2(<H2>) will halt. If it can't calculate whether H2(<H2>) will halt, then H isn't the program you think it is. That's a proof by contradiction.